# DB connection issue when trying to connect with Zend Framework Abstract.php No Such File Or Directory

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, zend-framework, mamp

I am trying to setup a ZF1 application on my local machine using MAMP. I am attempting to run the Ruckusing Database migrations, however it appears that ZF1 cannot connect to my DB.

This is the command I am running and the error I get.

```
crmpicco-MacBook:confirmation crmpicco$ php vendor/ruckusing/ruckusing-migrations/ruckus.php db:migrate ENV=development
Array
(
    [directory] => webapp
    [type] => mysql
    [host] => localhost
    [port] => 3306
    [database] => crmpicco_confirmation
    [user] => root
    [password] => root
    [socket] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
    [charset] => utf8
)

Abstract.php(144) : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Where should I look to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this.

I was using the standard PHP that comes with OSX by default.

I needed to change the command to use the PHP binary that comes installed with MAMP, e.g.

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php vendor/ruckusing/ruckusing-migrations/ruckus.php db:migrate ENV=development`

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks to [@tunder](https://github.com/tunder) ;)